# How to integrate Firebase Auth with next.js 13

Tags: firebase, next.js

I used to use Firebase for Authentication. In my `next.js` app, where to put the authentication functionality? If I put it in the Component the `FIREBASE_API_KEY` will be accessible.

### How to handle Auth in the Api routes handler? Or What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all.

For anyone who comes across this question in the future. After some progress in Next.js I found that there are better solutions for handling Authentication in Next.js such as [Auth.js (next-auth)](https://next-auth.js.org/) and [Clerk](https://clerk.com/solutions/nextjs-authentication).

If you still looking for a BaaS, [@geiel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76348929/18079514) is good or check out [Supabase](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth)

Comment: Hey. I'm from the future, and your answer has helped me

Answer (score 1):

It will depend of your needs, you can handle authentication both in the client or the server with Firebase, with next.js you can have [client components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive) and handle the authentication using the [official firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) for web apps, or you can have server components and use the Firebase Admin SDK [here](https://dev.to/geiel/how-to-use-firebase-authentication-in-nextjs-13-client-and-server-side-1bbn) is a good documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically use environment variables to keep your Firebase keys and other sensitive credentials secure. In Next.js, you can create a **.env.local** file in the root of your project to add environment variables. Check this [example code](https://github.com/victorfu/psyduck-next/blob/master/src/lib/firebase-admin-helper.ts).